# ¿Por qué no me cargan las imágenes en mi web con dominio?

Tags: javascript, html, imagen, bootstrap-5

Algunas imágenes sí cargan y otras no, que tengo guardadas en mi `directorio ejemplo img/nombre_carpeta/1.JPG, img/nombre_carpeta/2.JPG, etc...en mi página web, con dominio, cuando veo que las fotos no cargan solo queda con un logo de imagen no cargada, pero otro álbum de fotos que sí me muestra todas, las fotos de ese álbum, y no porque, puede que sea un problema de rutas donde uso los nombre con espacios="_", pero si me cargan en mi servidor localhost las imágenes que no me cargan en mi web.

Este álbum me carga bien las foto que sale en la siguiente imagen.
Estas son las rutas, que ocupo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese el código que no me carga las fotos

```
  <!-- Gallery -->
<div id="boton-frutillar">
    <div class="photo-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <h2 class="text-center"> ASESORIA A LA FISCALIZACION TECNICA DE OBRA DS-49 VIVIENDAS DE FRUTILLAR</h2>
                <p class="card-text text-center"><small class="text-muted">Año: 2021</small></p>
                <p class="card-text text-center"><small class="text-muted">Frutillar</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row photosp center-group">
            <script>
                for(let i=1; i<= 5; i++){
                document.write(
                `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item">
                    <a href="img/asesoria_frutillar_1/${i}.JPG" data-lightbox="photosp">
                        <img class="img-fluid imgcec" src="img/asesoria_frutillar_1/${i}.JPG">
                    </a>
                </div>`);
                }
            </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Gallery -->
```

aca tambien el codigo que si me cargan las imagenes correctamente, que se encuentra en la primera foto.

```
   <!-- Gallery -->
  <div id="boton-costanera">
      <div class="photo-gallery">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="intro">
                  <h2 class="text-center">Asesoría a la Inspección Técnica de obra del Proyecto Mejoramiento Parque Costanera de Puerto Montt</h2>
                  <p class="text-center">
                    Año: 2021-2022 <br>
                    Lugar: Puerto Montt
                  </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row photos center-group">
              <script>
                  for(let i=1; i<=10 ; i++){
                  document.write(
                  `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item">
                      <a href="img/proyecto_costP/${i}.JPG" data-lightbox="photos">
                          <img class="img-fluid imgcec" src="img/proyecto_costP/${i}.JPG">
                      </a>
                  </div>`);
                  }
              </script>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
<!-- Gallery -->
```

Esto pasa cuando muevo la imagen que no carga a otra pestaña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la la imagen que me carga bien con ruta img/proyecto_costP/1.jpg, usando el for como bucle, para cargar todas las fotos con variables llamadas i=1; i<=10; i++, para que carguen todas las fotos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca tengo las rutas que ocupo, pero el directorio img/asesoria_frutillar_1, cuando ocupo la misma estructura de fotos, no me resulta, siendo que ocupo el mismo for para llamar esas fotos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar código fuente (el que genera tu código) y mira si las rutas apuntan apropiadamente al lugar donde deberían.

Comment: asi sale la ruta src="img/programa_rural_ds/grupo_3_maullin_muermos/3.JPG"

Comment: nose, si pueden ser los guiones bajos que mayormente tengo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observaciones:

1. Cuando estás en alguna distribución Linuxera, los archivos son `case sensitive`, lo que quiere decir que `Archivo.jpg` es diferente de `archivo.jpg`.
2. Las rutas son muy importantes, si estás trabajando con rutas absolutas o relativas, siempre asegúrate que los archivos existan y se encuentren en el lugar donde deban estar.

En tu código:

Generas la ruta `img/proyecto_costP/${i}.JPG` y tu archivo tiene de nombre `img/proyecto_costP/1.jpg` (flashback al punto 1 de la observación).

Comment: igual cambio los nombres, a 1.JPG en mis directorios, pero nada

Comment: Pues vas a tener que publicar toda la estructura porque de ley los nombres de las rutas están para revisar.

Comment: hay las edite pa

Comment: Edita la pregunta nuevamente y coloca todas las rutas que han sido generadas. Coloca al costado todas las rutas de donde están las imágenes que deseas publicar.

Comment: encontre el problema, era que esas imagenes ya vienen predeterminado como png, pero les cambie por jpg, el jpg me causaba error, las cambie a png